# What happens if I change the disk with the EFI partition?

Tags: uefi

As much as I know UEFI/EFI is the successor of BIOS. I see that on my disk there is a partition called EFI System.

What happens if I replace that disk with an new and empty one? Will I ever be able to start the computer again as there is no EFI anymore?

Comment: Your machine firmware will follow it's instructions & provided whatever message(s) it has encoded for that, possible ":No bootable OS found" (and sits there; at least one box of mine does; another asks if you want to reboot & retry)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing a boot loader is a standard part of installing the operating system.

If you boot the OS install media with legacy or EFI methods, typically it will install the corresponding boot loader, which in the case of EFI, involves creating the EFI partition if necessary and rebuilding its contents.  So starting from a blank disk isn't a big deal.

Multiple operating systems can use the same EFI partition and each have a boot loader living there.

If your OS is already installed and you replace the disk containing the EFI partition (or destroy the partition somehow), you will need to go through boot recovery for each operating system to rebuild the EFI partition.  The EFI partition typically doesn't contain anything unique, so it should be possible to rebuild it.